# Using script editor to send an email from button in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make the button that I have on a sheet send an email using scripts but, I have not been able to get it to send the correct sheet or it sends a blank email.

I have tried a few different version of the Script but still can't get it to do anything I need it to.

I have 3 total sheets Sheet1 collects data for Sheet2. Sheet2 contains the Data I need to email and the button with the script to send the email. The third sheet is UserData which contains a list of emails that the data needs to be sent to.

```
...
function CustomEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getLastRow();
var UserData = range.getValues();
for (i in UserData) {
var row = UserData[i];
var email = row[1];
MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Shift Report", "Have a great Shift");
}
}
...
```

I hope to be able to input my data into Sheet1 and then review sheet two and hit the sendEmail button.

Comment: There are many email examples on this site do a little research and you’ll find a lot of answers on your own. You can start by debugging the script in the script editor because it contains errors.

Comment: been doing tons of digging and just cant find the specifics i need to make it work. I realize that there are errors in the code which is why Im reaching out, Im very new to both sheets and excel  not sure what i need to make it work so even if it is just letting me know why my code isnt working would help

Comment: Maybe Im going about this all wrong. Could i just copy an active sheet and ref another sheet to pull emails and send it?

Comment: Take a look at the [trouble shooting section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting) of the Apps Script Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function CustomEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getLastRow();
```

`getLastRow()` returns an integer not a range.

[getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

```
  var UserData = range.getValues();
```

Since range is not actually a range the above line will not produce any values.

```
  for (i in UserData) {
```

This sort of procedure should be reserved for objects with key/value pairs. And you should always declare your variables with var.

```
    var row = UserData[i];
    var email = row[1];
    MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Shift Report", "Have a great Shift");
  }
}
```